# jQuery .load() takes a long time when refreshing DOM element to reflect changes in php $_SESSION vars

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have the following javascript function. It is called when a user presses the action button. The code in doAction.php changes some $_SESSION variables, and on success I want to refresh the DOM element that displays these $_SESSION variables to the user.

Now, everything seems to work correctly however it takes about 3/5 seconds to show the changes in the DOM. I thought it was perhaps the AJAX call that was slow but the alert gets procced almost instantly when the button is pressed so it has to be the jQuery .load() right?

Is there any way to speed it up, the #container really is just a couple of lines. Should I use another method to refresh a DOM element? I don't want to refresh the entire page if possible..

Thanks in advance!

```
    $(document).on('click', '.btn-action', function(event) {
        var id = $(this).find('.btn-action-id').html();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: 'doAction.php',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {
                id: id
            },
            success: function (obj, textstatus) {
                alert("success!");
                $('#container').load(document.URL +  ' #container');
            },
            error: function (e) {
                alert(e);
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: Could your doAction.php just return the html you need rather than doing a nested load call - this way you are taking out the need to do 2 ajax calls and it should speed it up, or if it returns json data, just have placeholders for the values that you need to update rather than updating all the content

Comment: Excellent, I changed the code to do this. I am now returning the html directly from the doAction.php - essentially it was just copying it from my nested php where I echoed the $_SESSION variables to the doAction.php file. Then I load it using a jQuery .html() and it works instantaniously. Thanks! I wish I could accept your comment as an answer.

Comment: No probs, glad I could help